# Hummingbird cross Bering Strait

Tags: ornithology

Hummingbirds travel to Alaska during summer. If global warming continue, allow birds stay longer in Alaska, can hummingbirds cross Bering Strait to Russia, then spread in Asia?

Answer (score 1):

[The ruby-throated hummingbird flies 500 miles nonstop across the Gulf of Mexico during both its spring and fall migrations](https://www.thespruce.com/fun-facts-about-hummingbirds-387106)

[The Bering Strait is about 82 kilometres (51 mi) wide at its narrowest point, between Cape Dezhnev, Chukchi Peninsula, Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bering_Strait)

Based on the two facts above, it appears possible for a humming bird species to cross the Bering Straits if the weather becomes suitable to survival. Who would have thought?

That said, I am not sure how a humming bird who know which direction to fly in to make a successful crossing.

Comment: Good answer, I read Berng Strait have two Diomede Islands in center of strait, 40 km from both coasts. Probably need strong wind blow hummingbirds across, probably can't see islands from coasts.